# Powershell: Select single member from System.Object

Tags: powershell, psobject

I'm creating a script to pull certain fields from an API. I am currently using the following script:

```
$test | foreach-object {
new-object psobject -Property @{
    Service_Tag = $_.serviceTag
    ID = $_.id
    End_Date = $_.entitlements.endDate
    }
} | Format-Table Service_Tag, ID, End_Date
```

This will output:

```
Service_Tag         ID End_Date                                                                               
-----------         -- --------                                                                               
Tag1               ID1 {2024-03-17T04:59:59.000001Z, 2024-03-17T04:59:59.000001Z}                             
Tag2               ID2 {2024-06-28T04:59:59.000001Z, 2024-06-28T04:59:59.000001Z, 2026-06-28T04:59:59.000001Z}
```

The issue here is that End_Date field. I only need the first object. When I export the info to a csv (which is my end goal) it shows End_Date as "System.Object[]", the other two fields look fine.

How can I select just the first entry in that End_Date object?

I've tried accessing the object similarly to an array (i.e. End_Date[0]) But that doesn't work. Presumably the object is different from a normal array.

Comment: assuming no nulls, `$_.entitlements.endDate[0]` should be fine